# Is it possible to update the version of C++ compiler of OMNET++?

Tags: c++20, omnet++

I am running OMNET++ 5.6.2 on Ubuntu 20.04.4 and I want to make use of the C++20 features. According to my knowledge this version of OMNET++ uses C++11.
How to change the version of the C++ compiler of OMNET++?

Answer (score 1):

From https://github.com/omnetpp/omnetpp/blob/master/configure.user.dist, line no. 45, it says

```
    C++ specific compiler options. As OMNeT++ requires C++14 or later, this is
the place to specify -std=c++14 or a similar option if your compiler's default language compliance level is lower than C++14. These options will be used when compiling OMNeT++ and also when compiling simulation models.
```

You can check for CXXFLAGS=-std=c++20

Comment: my file contain this
# C++ specific compiler flags. OMNeT++ requires at least -std=c++11 (default), but
# -std=c++14 should work, too.
#CXXFLAGS=-std=c++11
I tried to change it to c++20, but it did not work

Comment: Obviously, you have to UNCOMMENT the line, too.

Comment: @Rudi Yes, I did uncommented the line, but it did not work!

Comment: Also, you MUST re-run the ./configure script after any change in the configure.user file.

Comment: @Rudi sorry for the stupid question, but how to do that? is it just by typing ./configure in terminal ?

Comment: Yes. In the root folder of OMNeT++. You did this already once when you installed OMNeT++.

Comment: @Rudi I tried but it only accepted C++14. I know that because when I run or build an OMNET++ project, the console indicates the version of the compiler.

Comment: sorry for a late reply, but you won't receive anything by updating `configure.user` file, it regulates only OMNeT++ compilation. What you probably wanted back there is to enable c++ 20 for **your OMNeT++ project**. In that case you need to go to `Properties->OMNeT++->makemake->your_makemake->Custom` and add there `CXXFLAGS += -std=c++20`. After build you will see a file `makefrag` with your custom instruction which is automatically included into a Makefile of your project. You can give any other compiler directive there as well